# UIButton inside table cell not changing attributes

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UIButton inside my cell together with an image and a text label. I manage to change the image and label programatically, but the UIButton does not seem to respond to anything except isHidden.
This is my code, the button that is not changing is followButton:

```
import UIKit

class ProfileTableCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var followButton: UIButton!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    self.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImage.frame.size.width/2;
    self.profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
    self.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: "belt")
    self.name.text = "Bar Refaeli"
    self.followButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.followButton.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
    self.followButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/4
    self.followButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}

func setCell(image: UIImage, name: String){

}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

The profileImage and name outlets change the appearance fine, like mentioned above.
I also tried to remove the button and bring it back in, clean xcode project, remove the outlet reference and connecting it again. Pretty frustrated by now.

I also tried to change the background color of the button through the storyboard, just for testing, and it does not change it! what does change is the titleLabel and the text color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awakeFromNib()- Prepares the receiver for service after it has been loaded from an Interface Builder archive, or nib file.

Given that, move your code to a view initiating method like  viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear(_:)

Child objects that are attributes like textLabels act differently than child view objects.

Comment: i will try it out, how would you explain the fact that changing the background color through storyboard doesn't do anything?

Comment: Its when you're calling it. Because of the view hierarchy. Next time you run it select the debug view hierarchy and rotate the storyboard to see what I mean.

Comment: I still did not solve it, but this is obviously the direction I am heading to, so marked it as solved.

Comment: Good luck! If I can see code and help you let me know. :-)

Comment: I tried to do the changes in the cellForRowAt index path (in my table view controller, rather than the actual cell) and it still does not work. I am not sure this is nib related..

Comment: Can you explain the whole feature and how you've architected it to date?

Comment: sure, can I email you tomorrow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135523/discussion-between-mrabins-and-sharonica).

Comment: please see the answer I added

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I actually solved this by tossing the table view to the garbage and implementing the same needs using a collection view. there was no problem there..